# apisauce gives network error on localhost

Tags: node.js, api, react-native

API Sauce is returning network error while testing API call from mobile on localhost

I tested my API on POSTMAN TOOL its gives proper output.But it does not work in the app properly

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough information to tell exactly what the problem is. But I'll assume you're trying to consume your API from a different device/machine/emulator(?) and when you test with POSTMAN you actually test on the same one running the API, hence the apparently surprising results.

In which case I would suggest you use the API machine IP instead of `localhost`.

example is, instead of doing

```
const apiClient = create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
  },
});
```

you rather do this

```
 const apiClient = create({
      baseURL: 'http://192.168.43.26:3000/api/v1',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
      },
    });
```

Notice that now instead of using "localhost" we use the actual (hypothetical) ip of the machine running the API: "192.168.43.26".